# How to add python "libraries" to Eclypse and pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, pydev

I am trying to learn how to use Abaqus Scripting. I just downloaded Eclipse and added the pydev plugin. Everything seems to work fine.

What I want to do now is to add all the built-in Abaqus libraries or modules.

- I would like, for example, the IDE to display the class members and methods when I press the ".".
- I would like to see if the code compiles fine without running it into Abaqus.

How can I do this in Eclipse? Or should I change IDE? Or is it not possible?

---

I just tried, but no success, I don't fully understand what I need to do. 
I am very much a beginner at Python (today is my second day). I have in the abaqus folder the python folder. It leads to two subfolders:

- **-lib: full of .pyc file (I guess precompiled Python files)**
- **-obj: full of windows dll and the python.exe which I guess is the interpeter.**

I also tried to add this interpreter but Eclipse said it can not add it (Error getting info on the interpreter)

I just added the whole lib and obj folder. Maybe once I get more involved in Python I can give you more detailed explanations.

---

New information:

When I try to run the script it says:

```
ImportError: Bad magic number in C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\6.9-1\Python\Lib\abaqus.pyc
```

Is there a compatibility problem, maybe with different versions of the Python interpreters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add these libraries to the settings to get the effect you want. This can be done in the `Libraries` setting accessed through `Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - Python > Libraries`. Add the `.egg` or source folder of the libraries you want to add and click `Apply` followed by `OK`.