# Pydev: Where do I have to add the path for an external lib (usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient)?

Tags: eclipse, pydev, mysql-python

I use mysqldb and pydev eclipse. I successfully compiled mysqldb 1.23 and now I would like to import it. mysqldb 1.23 needs the library libmysqlclient.18.dylib which lies in my case in /usr/local/mysql/lib. So when I start my test program in eclipse it crashes since it does not find the correct library. Therefore I need to tell eclipse where to find the libs.

How do I do this my case?

What and where in eclipse/pydev do I have to tell it that libmysqlclient.18.dylib resides in the above directoy?

The error message I get

```
ImportError: dlopen(/path/to/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /path/to/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 5):

In your project's properties, (accessible from `Project > Properties...`), click the `PyDev - PYTHONPATH` item. A view of your PYTHONPATH should be visible. Click the `External Libraries` tab and add your library. The next time you run, it should import correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I added the path as you said. But I still get the same error message. Is it possible to add the path manually in the run configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can add these libraries to the settings to get the effect you want. This can be done in the Libraries setting accessed through Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - Python > Libraries. Add the .egg or source folder of the libraries you want to add and click Apply followed by OK.

This ansqwer was provided by [How to add python "libraries" to Eclypse and pydev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675585/how-to-add-python-libraries-to-eclypse-and-pydev)