# How to use simplegui module when programming in python in eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, codeskulptor

I'm learning to program in Python now in a course via Coursera website. We are using an environment called "CodeSkulptor" and mainly using a module called "SimpleGUI".

I was wondering if there's any way to get the module sources and to attach them to eclipse so I can write in Python using this module in Eclipse instead of using CodeSkulptor all the time...

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add python "libraries" to Eclypse and pydev](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675585/how-to-add-python-libraries-to-eclypse-and-pydev)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I followed the steps but still can't get this working, my program returns an error "no such module simplegui"

Answer (score 3):

You can try [SimpleGUICS2Pygame](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleGUICS2Pygame).
Simply change
**import simplegui**
by
**import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui**
in your CodeSkulptor program and run it in standard Python with this module

Comment: Ok i've installed the module you told me, and also pygame. Now when I try to run a CodeSkulptor program, I don't get an error, but the program runs nothing. What do I need to do to see graphics?

Comment: I am not using Eclipse so I am not sure why it is not working. I am running it directly from my terminal.Even I was looking for a python package to run CodeSkulptor program on my system and found this package. I haven't tried many graphics program yet, but i did tried blackjack, pong and memory, and they worked properly.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible without getting the source of the library.

First of all, you should contact the developers and ask them to provide you a copy of the library "simplegui".

Furthermore, "Codeskulptor" is a tool which compile python and run it in the browser which make me think that simplegui is based on javascript.

Comment: Actually, I've tried to install the simplegui library I've got, and I get and error "no module named 'Tkinter'". Anyone can help?