# How integrate Abaqus python libraries into a project hosted in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, abaqus

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675585/how-to-add-python-libraries-to-eclypse-and-pydev) regarding the integration of Abaqus specific python libraries into a project hosted in `PyDev/Eclipse`. But unfortunately the answers were not compatible with my problem at hand.

I am using `ABAQUS` Version 6.11-2 and the Community Edition of `PyCharm 3.1.3`.
The Abaqus python interpreter resides at the following location on my windows7(64) machine.:

```
C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\6.11-2\Python\Obj\Python.exe
Python 2.6.2 for Abaqus 6.11-2 (r262:71600, Jun 29 2011, 19:23:41) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

The libraries I need PyCharm to resolve in order to give it's code completion magic a go are residing here - at least that's what I believe them to be.

```
C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\6.11-2\Python\Lib
C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\6.11-2\Python\Lib\abaqus.pyc
C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\6.11-2\Python\Lib\abaqusConstants.pyc
```

Here are the first lines of code of the script I am trying to work on.

```
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
backwardCompatibility.setValues(includeDeprecated=True, reportDeprecated=False)
import sketch
import part
```

PyCharm marks the abaqus and abaqusConstants import with red underlining. 
Showing:

```
 "Unresolved reference 'abaqus'".
```

Can someone explain to me how to configure the project in PyCharm so that PyCharm can resolve these imports?

Adding the mentioned Python.exe as a Project Interpreter in the Settings Dialog will lead to the following error messagebox saying 'Cannot setup a python SDK at ~path~. The SDK seems invalid'.

[image: Screenshot - SettingsDialog]

[image: Screenshot - ErrorMessageBox]

Regards

Comment: did you try to add the interpreter to the project interpreter?

Comment: I would recommend using the abqpy library in Python: https://abqpy.com It provides code completion for Abaqus commands in any IDE

Answer (score 5):

I'm using abaqus 6.14-4, hopefully helpful for you.
I think why we need PyCharm is because we want to fully use its type checker and other functions.
If we only need a editor, then Abaqus PDE is enough.

In order to achieve this goal, I have been search for abaqus python's source code for long time and couldn't find it. Since abaqus only provide the compiled *.pyc files, I use the tool uncompyle6 to decode the *.pyc files and add some functions in it.

There is my project:
[abaqus_pycharm](https://github.com/liangzulin/abaqus_pycharm)

1. register `\SIMULIA\Abaqus\6.14-4\tools\SMApy\python2.7\python.exe` as
   your interpreter (Or you can choose any you want)
2. copy the files at import-files folder to your site-packages folder

notices that this program used os.system command to run abaqus command line, shown as below:

```
def saveAs(self, pathName):
    if isinstance(self.debug, bool) and self.debug:
        print(pathName)
    if 'ABAQUS_BAT_SETTING' in os.environ.keys():
        self.abaqus_bat_setting = os.environ['ABAQUS_BAT_SETTING']
    if 'ABAQUS_BAT_PATH' in os.environ.keys():
        self.abaqus_bat_path = os.environ['ABAQUS_BAT_PATH']
    os.system(self.abaqus_bat_path + ' cae -' + self.abaqus_bat_setting + ' ' + os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
```

so we need to set environment like:

```
environ['ABAQUS_BAT_PATH'] = 'D:\\SIMULIA\\Abaqus\\Commands\\abaqus'
environ['ABAQUS_BAT_SETTING'] = 'noGUI'
```

and it will run as:

```
D:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\Commands\abaqus.bat -noGUI your_current_working_file.py
```

Answer (score 4):

Five years late to the party but this worked for me with Abaqus 2016 and PyCharm 2019.1 Professional on Windows 10:

1. Open Abaqus CAE, go to the Kernel Command Line Interface (the `>>>` icon) and enter the following:

```
>>> import os
>>> print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
C:\SIMULIA\CAE\2016;C:\SIMULIA\CAE\2016\win_b64;C:\SIMUL ...
```

2. Copy the output and make that your system-wide `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. I trimmed a repeat entry and some `.` paths.

[image: Setting System PYTHONPATH environment variable]

3. Restart PyCharm so it picks up the new `PYTHONPATH`, go to File/Settings/Project/Project Interpreter, click the Cog icon then Add. Choose the System Interpreter option then point it towards the `python.exe` in the Abaqus `bin` directory. In my case this was `C:\SIMULIA\CAE\2016\win_b64\code\bin\python.exe`. Don't be misled by other ones like `C:\SIMULIA\CAE\2016\win_b64\tools\SMApy\python2.7\python.exe` - they won't work.

This isn't bulletproof - for example, your line `from abaqus import *` won't work for me - even if I add `ABA_PATH` to the system path I get `ImportError: abaqus module may only be imported in the Abaqus kernel process`. But some debugging and code completion works, for example:

[image: Using the PyCharm debugger with Abaqus]

[image: Abaqus Python code completion in PyCharm]

Setting the system-wide path seemed a bit heavy-handed but I wasn't able to get it going any other way.